# Strptime with timezones and jq

Tags: bash, jq, strptime

Not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
getting_data | gunzip | jq -r '.time_field | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")'
```

The error comes back as such:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): date "2018-03-13T14:00:17.1614661Z" does not 
match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
```

The desired output would be `2018-03-13 14:00:17`

Comment: If you could provide the smallest working example of actual data (`echo '{"time_field": "2018-03-13T14:00:17.1614661Z"}' | ...`, maybe) rather than this `getting_data | gunzip` stub, others could test their answers.

Comment: btw, you can take the `Z` off both sides and see that the timezone has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Is the %f formatter capable of handling 7 figures? (1614661)

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, ...a more pertinent question is whether `%f` *exists at all* in the local libc (which requires specifying a specific platform, which the OP hasn't done).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that example you provided is how the dates are appearing so I am trying to parse that

Comment: @eagle, since you're here and answering questions: Which platform? Linux? MacOS? Something else? `jq` uses the libc's strptime call, so if we don't know your C library, we don't know which extensions (and thus which format specifiers) it supports.

Comment: sorry it's Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09 which I believe is RHEL Fedora

Comment: @charles-duffy %f does not exist on mine, Opensuse 42.3 :-(. How do I check libc version?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz yea disregard the `%f` I think it's inherent to Python, I was searching for ways to format nano seconds

Comment: I found a workaround I will post it in the edit, not sure if it is really efficient though, since I do not really care about the nano-seconds

Comment: Post your workaround as an answer, not an edit. An answer posted as an edit can't be voted on separate to the question itself, and is frowned on thusly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found a workaround to get around the ZULU offset and the nano-seconds since I do not really care so much about the nano-seconds. Not sure if it is efficient

```
echo '{"time_field": "2018-03-13T14:00:17.1234567Z"}' | jq -r '
.time_field 
| split(".")[0] 
| strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") 
| mktime 
| strftime("%F %X")'
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the timezone, but the nanoseconds field; `%f` is not available in standard `strptime` for C.

If you know your format won't change, there's no particular reason to use `strptime` or `strftime` at all:

```
jq -r '.time_field | sub("^(?<date>[[:digit:]-]+)T(?<time>[[:digit:]:]+)[.].*";
                         "\(.date) \(.time)")' \
  <<<'{"time_field": "2018-03-13T14:00:17.1614661Z"}'
```

...properly emits:

```
2018-03-13 14:00:17
```